# GWT log file when deployed

Tags: gwt, tomcat, logging

i have a `GWT` web application project and i will deploy it to `Tomcat`. before deploying it, i want to set a log file so that i can trace if some errors occur like `JavaScriptException`. how can i do this?

as i did some research, i've read that GWT's default logging does not emulate the `FileHandler` that allow me write my log file to a specific file. Then from some forums about logging, someone has been using `log4j` but `log4j` is for `Java` (am i right?).

how can i do the logging for my `GWT` app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [built in logging capabilities of GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging). In particular you will be mostly interested in [remote logging](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Remote_Logging), which sends log messages logged on the client to the server in an RPC call (obviously you only want to use this in exceptional circumstances).

You can also use the [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) project and consider using the `RemoteLogger`.