# GWT logging in production mode

Tags: gwt, logging

How to see GWT logs in production mode?
In dev mode,i can see in eclipse.I am hosting my GWT application in apache web server.

Please let me know your suggestions on this.

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274514/gwt-log-file-when-deployed

Comment: You should have a look on log4j

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted a complete working sample code in the same context.

Read it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049560/serialize-java-lang-throwable-along-with-stack-trace-causes-chain-and-related-s/22082078#22082078) where `RemoteLoggingService` is used to send the logs from client to server side.

Read more on [GWT DevGuide - Overview of the Logging Framework](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Overview_of_the_Logging_Framework)